# when is Javascript's Map.forEach evaluated?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript Map data type to store some data.

```
const map = new Map();
map.set("DATA1", 0);
map.set("DATA2", 0);
...
```

Let's say I have some parallel task like a cron-job that periodically updates the map like so:

```
new CronJob(
  "* * * * *",
  async () => {
    const target = SomeApi.getTarget();
    map.set(target.key, map.get(target.key) + target.count);
  },
)
```

Now assume there are thousands and thousands of elements stored in this map.
When I invoke `forEach` on the map to perform some task, for example

```
map.forEach((count) => {
  if(count === 0) {
    someBusinessLogic(count);
  } else {
    someOtherBusinessLogic(count);
  }
})
```

does forEach read the **entire map data at the moment of** `map.forEach` **call** ?
or does it evaluate **each element at the time of its iteration**?

In other words, in my example code, if the value of key "DATA1000" was 0 at the time of `map.forEach()` call,
but then the cron job updated its value to 1 by the time `forEach` iterated to the element "DATA1000",

will the value of "DATA1000" be 0 or 1?

Comment: You’ll surely get a better answer but js was built as a single threaded language (single thread interpreter) and the only chance to go multithread is using web workers (added not long ago) and you can’t easily manipulate data from there. There’s data thread safety enforced through a messaging strategy between them and the main caller. The foreach will call the callback at each iteration and that data won’t be mutated in the meanwhile afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does `forEach` read the entire map data at the moment of `map.forEach` call ?
> or does it evaluate each element at the time of its iteration?

It does so at the moment of its iteration. But read on...

> if the value of key "DATA1000" was 0 at the time of `map.forEach()` call,
> but then the cron job updated its value to 1 by the time `forEach` iterated to the element "DATA1000", will the value of "DATA1000" be 0 or 1?

This cannot happen. The cron job cannot run before the `forEach` loop has ended. The cron job will only get its turn when the current execution has run to completion and the call stack becomes empty, and there is something in the job queues that makes the engine call or resume the cron job.

So only code that is called as part of the `forEach` callback needs to be considered when you ask yourself if anything in the Map will have changed that influences the next iterations of `forEach`.